Does Interpol have the capability to repatriate Sheikh Hasina overriding Indian state protection?

Sheikh Hasina’s exile: Lutyens bungalow, heavy security cover

Sheikh Hasina is living in New Delhi, India, with federal-level security.

Bangladesh asks Interpol for help in arresting ousted Prime Minister Sheikh Hasina

Bangladesh has requested Interpol to help repatriate Sheikh Hasina with an accusation of crime against humanity.

Does Interpol have the capability to repatriate Sheikh Hasina overriding Indian state protection?


Does Interpol have the capability to repatriate Sheikh Hasina overriding Indian state protection?

No, because Interpol doesn't have the authority or means to arrest anyone. Interpol itself is not a law enforcement agency. They don't employ any field agents with special privileges.
Interpol is a collaboration between different national law enforcement organization that primarily serves as a means of information exchange. Mostly in form of "interpol notices", which advise any national police organization to look for certain people and possibly observe or apprehend them if they show up within their legal jurisdiction. Such notices are requested by national police organizations. Interpol will then decide whether or not the notice is warranted. They refused to issue notices in the past on grounds that they believed them to be primarily politically motivated. If they decide that issuing a notice is warranted, then they will forward that notice to all national police organizations in the world.
But what to do with that information is up to the national police organizations. If a country decides not to bother a person with an interpol notice on their head within their jurisdiction, then there is nothing Interpol will or can do about that.
This is a diplomatic matter that can only be resolved between states. Pakistan can't obligate India to extradite Sheikh Hasina. But they could try to convince or coerce them, if they can find an appropriate carrot or stick.

Interpol doesn't go around and arrest people. What Interpol does is to spread the information that some member country seeks the arrest of a particular person. This is useful if the sought person travels, because a country they travel through might hold them until an extradition request can be made and assessed.
As long as Hasina remains in New Delhi, an Interpol notice against her is not going to accomplish anything. The Indian government already knows that the new government of Bangladesh seeks her arrest, and they don't seem particularly inclined to extradite her.
